# how to display index of row and column in the following code

Tags: python, numpy, row, enumerate

Have to display elements according to their rows and columns.

```
import numpy as np
b = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
print(b)
b5 = np.where( b >5)
c=b[b5]

print("***Values of where the elements are, and their rows/columns***")
for row,col in enumerate(b):
    for j in c:
        if col in c:
            print("Value:",j,"in row",row,", column",col)
```

```
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]

***Values of where the elements are, and their rows/columns***
Value: 6.0 in row 2 , column [6. 7. 8.]
Value: 7.0 in row 2 , column [6. 7. 8.]
Value: 8.0 in row 2 , column [6. 7. 8.]
```

Expected to show column number. 
ie. Value: 6.0 in row 2 , column 0

Answer (score 0):

The indices are in `b5` you just need to extract them:

```
for row, col, val in zip(*b5, c):
   print("row", row, "col", col, "val", val)
```

prints:

```
row 2 col 0 val 6.0
row 2 col 1 val 7.0
row 2 col 2 val 8.0
```